# Multiple AJAX Calls Sharing Same Dataset in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Razor View within my MVC 5 application, which when hit calls 5 JavaScript functions.

Inside each of the 5 JavaScript functions, there is an AJAX call to the associated method in my MVC Controller, each of which returns JSON data.

So...

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

LoadData1();
LoadData2();
LoadData3();
LoadData4();
LoadData5();

function LoadData1()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/MyController/GetData1/',
        //Rest of code});
}

//Rest of LoadData methods

});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult GetData1()
{

 var query = _myService.GetData();
 //Rest of code
}

[HttpGet]
public ContentResult GetData2()
{

 var query = _myService.GetData();
 //Rest of code
}

//Rest of controller methods GetData3 etc...
```

The above approach works, however, inside each of the 5 Controller methods (GetData1, GetData2 etc...) the query (`var query = _myService.GetData()`) is called in each of them, therefore, the same data set is being returned. My problem, is that I don't want to have to call the same query five times in each of the 5 Controller methods. Each Controller method is working with the returned query data very differently, therefore, each method still needs to exist.

However, is there some way I can call the query (`var query = _myService.GetData()`) once per HttpRequest somewhere in the Controller, and then pass the returned data to each Controller method that needs it?

This would vastly improve the re-usability of code and also the performance for the end user.

I've never done anything like this before and I'm not sure if what I'm (trying) to describe is even possible?

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: cache the result from the service call, and have the controllers work on the cached data

Comment: You are calling the query once per request (you are making 6 requests - the original GET and 5 ajax calls). But why are you doing this instead or returning all the data in the original GET?

Comment: Couldn't you call the controller once, and then pass the returned dataset to your subsequent functions where they work with the data in their own way instead of them doing their own ajax calls?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi. I thought there were 5 calls to the query (one each per ajax call)? I was thinking about just having one GET method in my controller, but each of the GET methods contain quite a bit of complicated code manipulating the data etc. That's why I have 5 different GET methods. To keep my code cleaner. Maybe this isn't the correct approach?

Comment: @topher thanks, this is something I should consider.

Comment: @3dd thanks, again this is something I've ever done, but I will look into it.

Comment: You can refactor the code into separate private methods where each processes and returns the data you want to the main action method

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, I quite like this idea, similar to what topher has suggested

Answer (score 1):

You are not making 1 request -- you are making 1 request to load the page and then 5 requests to get data.  You are not able to persist data like that across calls unless you look at using the cache.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx

The thought I have is that your controller methods should first check the cache to see if the item exists, if so, then pull it out and return it.  If the item does not exist, then \ call `.GetData()` and immediately store it in the cache before returning the data.  You can also set some options up to expire the data after a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this is definitely an option for me.

Comment: @tcode While this does what you ask, I am not a fan of persisting data in the cache (I generally only persist temporary items such as a user building a configuration or model).  I would look to see if you can return the data in your first javascript method, then use multiple functions on success to parse it.  If the data should be the same every time, avoid making multiple GETS, just have multiple javascript functions to operate on the same data.

Answer (score 0):

To make Jason's answer more concrete, an option is to use the [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) class to cache the data across AJAX calls for a specified time period as follows:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;

[HttpGet]
public ContentResult GetData1()
{
    var query = GetData();
    //Rest of code
}

public object GetData()
{
    string key = "myDataKey";
    object data = MemoryCache.Default.Get(key) as object;  // specify your type instead of object

    if (data == null)  // not in cache, need to go to DB
    {
        data = _myService.GetData();

        // Cache it for 5 minutes.
        DateTimeOffset duration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
        MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(key, data, duration);
    }
        
    return data;
}
```

You might need to put a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) around the code in `GetData()` if thread synchronization is an issue.